# A completed callback for .on('xxx')?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Currently on a dashboard page I'm pulling the top 25 comments and displaying them with this code

```
fba.orderByChild('when').limitToLast(25).on('child_added', function (d, c) { stuff });
```

But the function is called for each child - is there a callback that can be triggered when the series of calls are complete other than wrapping the whole call in a Promise?

I'm thinking I need to change this block to use .once('value') at the start then attach a listener for child_added with >TIMESTAMP.

Is this the preferred approach for something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase `child_` events are indeed invoked for each child independently. They are great for building and updating a UI element for each child.

*Keep in mind that Firebase data is synchronized: when a new child is added, you will receive one `child_added` event and one `child_removed` event. This makes it easy to do a minimal update to the UI.*

If you want to get all matching elements in bulk, use the `value` event:

```
fba.orderByChild('when')
   .limitToLast(25)
   .on('value', function (snapshot) {
       snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
           // child is now the snapshot of a specific child
       });
   });
```

*If in this scenario a new child is added, the `value` event willget all children again. So if you're updating a UI, you'll be rebuilding the entire UI. Not wrong, just different.*

Comment: I went for the initial load with once('value') and ordered the information in an array (needed reverse sorting) before rendering which worked great.  A code sample I found on github gave me the example to then trigger the .on('child_added') with >TIMESTAMP as the query so I only then get passed new items.  Having a "completed" callback on child_added would be great for post processing work. I tried the fireproof promise wrapper but after the initial load nothing would trigger.  Splitting the code into two calls did the job.

Comment: Doing a single `value` and then `child_added` from the last child is indeed a perfectly valid approach. Firebase does continuous data synchronization, so there is no moment that the `child_added` calls "completed". A new child might appear at any time. So you can ask for "the value" or for "any actions related to children".